# How to Count Children Nodes on Javascript Fancytree?

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I created a Category tree using Fancytree with Drag & Drop Functionality like

[image]

Now, I want to set limit for child node. if parent node already have 3 child node then his not able to create new child not for example

**Category**

parent category

- child category Allowed

  - Child Category Allowed

    - Child Category Not Allowed to Move

like this so i create javascript for this.

```
dragDrop: function(node, data) {
if( node.getLevel() >= 3 ){
    return false;
}
console.log( node );
console.log( data );
var parentNodeKey = node.key;
var sourceNode = $(data.helper).data("ftSourceNode");
if( !data.otherNode ){
    var title = $(data.draggable.element).text() + " (" + (count)++ + ")";
    node.addNode({title: title}, data.hitMode);
    return;
}
data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
```

}

This is working fine when i move any single category. but this is not working when i move "Moved Node" category because this category already have a 2 child node and that child node already have 2 child nodes like

[image]

I move the "Moved Node" and this is Working how can i count that child nodes or stop to moved that nodes. i want to set limit for creating 3 child nodes. How can i do this. and how can i count the all child nodes of moveing category.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Child nodes can be counted using [`node.countChildren`](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#countChildren), but from your description I guess you want to count the maximum *level* of child nodes?

There is no builtin method for that, but you can implement it using `node.visit()`.

Comment: In case, what to do if I want to see whether do I have any node [parent/child] or not?